# Which one is right - "he did leave" or "he did leaves"?

Tags: tense, auxiliary-verbs

Could we said: "he did leave the house"  or "he did leaves the house"?

Comment: "He did leaves" could mean he was raking the garden in autumn, but apart from that, it makes no sense...

Comment: The form in "-s" is never ever ever used after an auxiliary.

Comment: Or smoking certain  leaves. @Alexander

Answer (score 1):

He did leave - the structure "*did + bare infinitive*" makes past tense.

e.g. I did leave, you did leave, he did leave, we did leave, you (pl) did leave, they did leave.

**For example:**

- I did see
- You did eat
- They did complain

Answer (score 1):

We would say **he left the house**.

When not necessary, *do* is added before the verb only when you want to emphasize your point. For instance:

> Person A: I've heard you don't have the piano anymore.
>
> Person B: Oh, that's not true! I **do** have the piano!

Taken from: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40875/why-is-do-sometimes-put-before-a-verb

Answer (score 1):

After 'do' as an auxiliary verb in questions or negatives, or for emphasis, comes the base form of the following verb, in this case 'leave'.

Note that 'he did leave' is not the most common way to say this - the most common way is 'he left'. 'He did leave' is usually emphasised:

Boss (talking about a sick worker): Why didn't he leave when I told him?
Secretary: He *did* leave. He just came back to get something before he goes home.